# PHP math method

Tags: laravel, math

My `Share` class hasMany `Grant` class (related). 
my `grants` table has `shares_amount`.

So I displayed total `shares_amount` for each `Share` class with this function:

```
public function totalIssued()
{
    return $this->grants->sum('shares_amount');
}
```

And all correct.

But now I need to find sum of each `totalIssued()` function for each `Share` class.

Screenshot will help: http://joxi.ru/Y2LBgLyi9EpLDr

Please any tips.

Comment: have you tried looping the collection of `Share` model and calculated it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### With Loop

Suppose you have a collection of `Share`:

```
$shares = \App\Share::all();
```

Then to retrieve the total, you could loop through each of them to sum it to a total variable.

```
$total = 0;
$shares->each(function ($share) use (&$total) {
    $total += $share->totalIssued();
});
```

Or via the `foreach` loop:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($shares as $share) {
    $total += $share->totalIssued();
}
```

### Without Loop

```
\App\Share::join('grants', 'shares.id', '=', 'grants.share_id')
    ->sum('grants.shares_amount');
```

Comment: @PhilippNoris No problem, have a nice day! :)

Comment: I used foreach way